# Download SFTP file to Remote server folder directly (not to shared path)

Tags: java, sftp, jsch

I want to develop a java program to download a file from SFTP server to remote server. That remote server doesn't have any shared path. I have to directly download from sftp and paste in remote windows server driver (D:).

code:

```
 int ftpPort = 22;

    JSch jsch = new JSch  ();
         Session session = null;
         Channel channel = null;
         ChannelSftp c = null;

        try {

        session = jsch.getSession(username, hostname, ftpPort);
        logger.info("***   FTP Session created.   ***");
        session.setPassword(password);

        Properties config = new Properties();
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.setConfig(config);
        session.connect();
        logger.info("***   Session connected.   ***");

        //Open the SFTP channel
        logger.info("***   Opening FTP Channel.   ***");
        channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
        channel.connect();
        c = (ChannelSftp) channel;

        //Change to the remote directory
        logger.info("***   Changing to FTP remote dir: " + remoteDirectory + "   ***");
        c.cd(remoteDirectory);

        //Send the file we generated
        try {
                logger.info("***   Storing file:'" + filename + "' to local directory: '"+localDirectory+"'");
```

I am using Jsch and ChannelSftp for connecting to SFTP server.

As of now the above code downloads the code to local path and shared path.

Any suggestion to download the files to Remote server(windows) which doesn't hav any shared path.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your code would need to run on the remote server directly and download the files from SFTP to its local disk.

Another way would be to download the file on your local machine using your code and then use something like SCP to transfer the file on the remote server, if you really don't have any shared folders.

```
scp /path/to/your/file user@host:/remote/path
```

But you said, it's Windows, so you might need to set up SSH/SCP first on that machine.